# List all the compositions by a specific composer in their profile details page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want a public page showing the profile of a specific user (so I cannot grab the user id from the logged-in users). I'm not able to select their specific compositions.

I am using a custom user model, so that I have a User class and then a Profile class which is linked to the User via OneToOneField (see code below). I also have a Composition class, which is linked to a specific composer via a ForeignKey. I am able to get the details of a specific profile  and I'm also able to print out all the compositions (using Composition.objects.all()).

My models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = UserManager()
[...]

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
[...]
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[str(self.id)])

class Composition(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(
      USER, #my custom user model
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("composition-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

My views.py:

```
def profile_details(request, id):
    compositions = Composition.objects.filter(composer__id=id)
    context = {
        "object_list": compositions
    }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

My urls.py:

`path('profile/<int:id>/', views.profile_details, name='profile')`

My template.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.full_name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ obj.profile_id}}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user }}</p>
          {% for composition in object_list %}
          <li><a href="{{ composition.get_absolute_url }}">{{ composition.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm expecting to see the compositions by that specific composer, i.e. user associated to the profile I'm viewing.

**Edit**

I've made some progress by adding some custom data to my view:

```
class ProfileDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['compositions'] = Composition.objects.filter(id=1)
        return context
```

Now the `context` contains indeed all the composition. How do I filter only the composition by the user connected to the profile I'm viewing?

Comment: Hang on, is `id` here the id of the user or the profile? Show the rest of the view and template.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Ah, sorry, a few lines were not showing for the views/model, and I've now included the whole template. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As you can see the composer is linked to the user id, not the profile id (I think!)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman It'd also be ideal (and maybe better) if I could have something like mysite.com/profile/<full_name> in the URL, so that I can then grab (is it possible?) the <full_name> from the URL, and pass it to the compositions filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests I've apparently finally come to a solution.

My views.py:

```
def profile_details(request, pk):
    compositions = Composition.objects.filter(composer__id=pk)
    context = {
        "compositions": compositions,
    }
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)
```

And my urls.py:

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile_details, name='profile')
```

The `pk`, which is the same for User and Profile objects, is taken from the URL, and used for filtering the `Composition` objects and find only the compositions by that composer.